# Convert csh script to bash script

Tags: bash, csh

I am currently converting a csh script on linux to a bash script on Mac OS X lion.

The csh script looks like:

```
setenv CNS_SOLVE '/Users/ucbthsa/Documents/haddock2.1/software/bin/'
setenv CNS_SOLVE $CNS_SOLVE
if ( -d $CNS_SOLVE ) then
    if ( ! $?CNS_ARCH ) setenv CNS_ARCH `$CNS_SOLVE/bin/getarch`
else
    setenv CNS_ARCH 'unknown'
endif
```

My conversion to a Mac bash script looks as follows:

```
export CNS_SOLVE='/Users/ucbthsa/Documents/haddock2.1/software/bin/cns_solve_1.3'
export CNS_SOLVE=$CNS_SOLVE

if [ -d $CNS_SOLVE ]; then
  if [ ! $?CNS_ARCH ]; then
    export CNS_ARCH='$CNS_SOLVE/bin/getarch'
else
  export CNS_ARCH='unknown'
endif
```

When I try and source the Mac bash script I get the following error:

> -bash: cns_solve_env: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file

I cannot understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: "fi" instead of "endif"?

Comment: Oh and there's also the second if that's not closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `fi` rather than `endif` and you aren't closing the first if at all:

```
export CNS_SOLVE='/Users/ucbthsa/Documents/haddock2.1/software/bin/cns_solve_1.3'
export CNS_SOLVE=$CNS_SOLVE

if [ -d $CNS_SOLVE ]; then
  if [ -z $CNS_ARCH ]; then
    export CNS_ARCH="$CNS_SOLVE/bin/getarch"
  fi
else
  export CNS_ARCH='unknown'
fi
```

*edit: changed the second test, as William Pursell pointed out, it wouldn't work as it was in bash.

Comment: `! $?CNS_ARCH` will always evaluate false, since the string being tested will always be `XCNS_ARCH` where `X` is the value of `$?`.

Comment: You should double-quote when you expand variables: `[ -d "$CNS_SOLVE" ]` and especially `[ -z "$CNS_ARCH" ]` to avoid parsing confusion.  Also, single-quotes prevent variable expansion, so use `export CNS_ARCH="$CNS_SOLVE/bin/getarch"`

Answer (score 0):

`$?CNS_ARCH` means something different in  sh.  Use:

```
test -z "$CNS_ARCH" && CNS_ARCH=$($CNS_SOLVE/bin/getarch)
```

or

```
CNS_ARCH=${CNS_ARCH-$( $CNS_SOLVE/bin/getarch)}
```

Notice that these have slightly different meanings.  The first is will assign to CNS_ARCH if CNS_ARCH is already set but is the empty string, while the second will not change CNS_ARCH if it is already set, but is empty, which is what the `$?` does in csh, but is probably not what you actually want.